# java regex matching each group starting with specific string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `a1wwa1xxa1yya1zz`.

I would like to get every groups starting with a1 until next a1 excluded. 
(In my example, i would be : `a1ww`, `a1xx`, `a1yy`and `a1zz`

If I use :

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(a1.*?)a1").matcher("a1wwa1xxa1yya1zz");
while(m.find()) {
  String myGroup = m.group(1);
}
```

`myGroup` capture 1 group every two groups.
So in my example, I can only capture `a1ww` and `a1yy`.

Anyone have a great idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split is a good solution, but if you want to remain in the regex world, here is a solution:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(a1.*?)(?=a1|$)").matcher("a1wwa1xxa1yya1zz");
while (m.find()) {
  String myGroup = m.group(1);
  System.out.println("> " + myGroup);
}
```

I used a positive lookahead to ensure the capture is followed by `a1`, or alternatively by the end of line.

Lookahead are zero-width assertions, ie. they verify a condition without advancing the match cursor, so the string they verify remains available for further testing.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is good to me as I don't have to modify my code to match the answer with splits. Furthermore, it made me understand the lookahead better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split()` method, then append "a1" as a prefix to splitted elements:

```
String str = "a1wwa1xxa1yya1zz";
String[] parts = str.split("a1");
String[] output = new String[parts.length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
    output[i] = "a1" + parts[i + 1];

for (String p : output)
    System.out.println(p);
```

**Output:**

```
a1ww
a1xx
a1yy
a1zz
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was good enough for me but regexp one was simpler/faster to implement.

Comment: @user1897948 _split()_ is also based on regex. anyway, you prefer.

Comment: @ivanovic why don't you use `i+1` instead of your separate `index` variable?

Comment: @jlordo thanks dude, i wrote an enhanced for-loop on first scratch, that's why it remained there =)

Comment: @jlordo thanks dude, i wrote an enhanced for-loop on first scratch, that's why it remained there =)

Comment: @jlordo thanks dude, i wrote an enhanced for-loop on first scratch, that's why it remained there =)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an approach like this:

```
    String str = "a1wwa1xxa1yya1zz";
    String[] parts = str.split("a1");
    for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
        String found = "a1" + parts[i];
    }
```